# What tool do I need to visualize world map with straight border while keeping its area and neighboring countries

Tags: proximity, nearest-neighbor, voronoi-thiessen, borders, cartogram

I am fairly new to data visualization.

My goal is:

1. Turning country area into right angled polygon with same area
2. Keeping the neighboring country tangent to its new border
3. Finding the new arrangement that is compact i.e. like a floor plan

I need to keep the same area and neighboring countries. Russia could be in the middle of Africa for all I care.

I was considering modifying the Thiessen polygon method in QGIS
before:
input variable=
-distance to nearest neighboring point (countries)
output= area
after:
input variable=
-country area
-neighboring countries tangent to that country
output= new capital/country arrangement.

I am not sure if my plan is possible, especially for beginner, or if there are ways with less hassle.

Comment: So the shape must be always a rectangle? And the topolofy must be preserved for all countries except Russia? Do you care about mini-states like the Vatican or Liechtenstein?

Comment: shape is preferably rectangle yes, unless it's it's mathematically impossible, then any irregular polygon is okay as long as the border must always be horizontal or vertical. and yes, i do intend to incorporate microstate

Comment: Are you sure you wish to maintain each country's area? The usual application of an *area cartogram* -- the thing you seem to want -- is to distort each country's area to match some *other* useful statistic.

Comment: These two sentences appear to me to be complete contradictions: "I need to keep the same area and neighboring countries. Russia could be in the middle of Africa for all I care."

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are looking for a rectangular [cartogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartogram). I've never tried it but a quick google points to [an R package `recmap`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/recmap/versions/1.0.9/topics/recmap). There is also a paper [*On rectangular cartograms* by Marc van Kreveld, Bettina Speckmann (doi:10.1016/j.comgeo.2006.06.002)](https://bspeckmann.win.tue.nl/papers/RectanCarto.pdf) which discusses the method of creating them.

Answer (score 1):

A semi-manual approach:

1. create a square inside each country with a size proportional to the area of the country using this expression with `Menu Processing / Toolbar / Geoemtry by expression` (see screenshot 1 below). You can change the coefficient (here: `*0.3`) at the end of line 5 that changes the size of the square according to your needs:

```
make_regular_polygon( 
    pole_of_inaccessibility( $geometry,100),
    project (
        pole_of_inaccessibility( $geometry,100),
        sqrt(area($geometry))*0.3,
        radians (45)
    ),
    4
)
```

2. Activate `snapping`, mark one square after the other, activate `Move feature` and move it topologically as good as possible. You'll not succeed 100%, but for the moment we just need an approximation (see screenshot 2).
3. Subdivide each square in 100 smaller squares. Use this expression (again with Geoemtry by expression) to generate lines divding each square in 10x10 stripes (see screenshot 3):

To get 10 vertical stripes:

```
with_variable(
    'dist',
    length (make_line (point_n( $geometry, 1), point_n( $geometry, 2)))/10,
    
        collect_geometries (
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (1,9),
                make_line (
                    project (
                        point_n( $geometry, 3),
                        @dist*@element,
                        radians (90)),
                    project (
                        point_n( $geometry, 4),
                        @dist*@element,
                        radians (90))
        )))
)
```

To get 10 horizontal stripes:

```
with_variable(
    'dist',
    length (make_line (point_n( $geometry, 1), point_n( $geometry, 2)))/10,
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1,9),
            make_line (
                project (
                    point_n( $geometry, 3),
                    @dist*@element,
                    radians (0)),
                project (
                    point_n( $geometry, 2),
                    @dist*@element,
                    radians (0)
)))))
```

4. Now split the squares from above with the lines from step 4 using `Menu Processing / Toolbox /Split with lines`. First split the square with the horizontal lines, thin again split the result with the vertical lines.
5. Now move some of the small squares as described in step 2 to reconstruct a correct topology (see screenshot 4). It's a trial and error and it will not work 100%, generating some overlapping. However, the result is more or less what you want.

When finished, you might want to merge together all small squares of the same country back to one polygon. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate` and aggregate based on an attribute like name.

*Screenshot 1, creating proportional squares (here with Geometry generator for demonstration purpose):*
[image]

*Screenshot 1a: this, by the way, is a world map with all countries in a Sphere cylindrical equal area projection from which the squares were built with the expression from above:*
[image]

*Screenshot 2: Placing the squares as good as possible. However, as you see, we can't place all countries to border correctly all their neighbors (and only them). France e.g. should border Italy; Belgium borders France and Luxemburg, but not Germany and so on:*
[image]

*Screenshot 3: dividing squares in 100 sub-squares (here with geometry generator and both expressions combined for demonstration purpose - however you should do it as described in step 3):*
[image]

*Screenshot 4: moving the small squares:*
[image]