# Plot shapefile as squares

Tags: python, geopandas, image

I am trying to plot a US shapefile as squares instead of showing the actual boundaries.

I can plot a shapefile like this...

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
State_Shp = '.../cb_2018_us_state_500k/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp'
State_Shapefile = gpd.read_file(State_Shp)
State_Shapefile = State_Shapefile.to_crs("epsg:4326")
a  = ["MP", "HI", "VI" ,"AS", "AK", "PR","GU"]
State_Shapefile = State_Shapefile[~State_Shapefile['STUSPS'].isin(a)]
State_Shapefile['randNumCol'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, State_Shapefile.shape[0])
State_Shapefile.plot(column='randNumCol')
```

[image]

However, how can I get an image such as this? I apologize for the bad image quality.

[image]

Comment: You need to search for [**cartogram**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=cartogram)

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408882/what-tool-do-i-need-to-visualize-world-map-with-straight-border-while-keeping-it answer your question?

Comment: I decided to go a separate route. https://www.kaggle.com/code/poznyakovskiy/us-tile-grid-map/notebook

Comment: please add it as an answer for future users

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to take a different route by not using a shapefile but rather a file that takes into account position and row of the state similar to what is mentioned here...
kaggle.com/code/poznyakovskiy/us-tile-grid-map/notebook